# Display Link Within Django ModelForm Based On Dropdown Value Selected

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-forms

I am using class-based generic views and a forms.ModelForm as the `form_class` attribute. How would you make a link appear inside the ModelForm dependent on a form's dropdown value?

---

I uploaded this minimal, reproducible example to [GitHub HERE](https://github.com/jaradc/SO939393).

```
git clone https://github.com/jaradc/SO939393.git
```

---

**What I am trying to achieve**: when an item from a dropdown is selected, show link to a file below the dropdown instantly after selection.

Visually:

1. Form loaded on the request
2. User selects an item from the "Model one" dropdown
3. Some internal process:

   1. Gets the ModelOne `sample_input_file` location
   2. Injects that location as a link into the form below the "Model one" field

[image: show link in Django ModelForm]

---

**QUICK VIEW (this IS the entire project)**

If this is too overwhelming, you can ignore it! I'm providing it for full context in-case someone wants to see every detail.

Project name: SO939393

App name: myapp

**SO939393/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
]
```

**SO939393/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
]
```

**myapp/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class ModelOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    large_pickle_file = models.FileField()
    sample_input_file = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model_one = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upload_file = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**myapp/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('create/', views.Create.as_view(), name='create')
]
```

**myapp/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import ModelTwo

class ModelTwoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelTwo
        fields = ['name', 'model_one', 'upload_file']
```

**myapp/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .forms import ModelTwoForm
from .models import ModelTwo

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = ModelTwo
    template_name = 'myapp/base.html'

class Create(CreateView):
    form_class = ModelTwoForm
    model = ModelTwo
    template_name = 'myapp/create_form.html'
    success_url = '/'
```

**myapp/templates/myapp/base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
    <h1><a href="{% url 'create' %}">Create</a> an Item</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for item in object_list %}
            <li>{{ item.name }} - {{ item.model_one.name }}</li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>No items yet.</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
{% block custom_js %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**myapp/templates/myapp/create_form.html**

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container col-5">
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block custom_js %}<script>{% static 'myapp/custom.js' %}</script>{% endblock %}
```

**myapp/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ModelOne, ModelTwo

admin.site.register(ModelOne)
admin.site.register(ModelTwo)
```

**myapp/static/myapp/custom.js**

```
# this file is empty but mentioning just in-case javascript is the way to go here
```

Answer (score 0):

100% credit goes to this Vitor Freitas blog post on [How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html). Without it, I would have never learned this technique and this was literally the first time I used AJAX.

If anyone actually follows this, you'll have to create a superuser and migrate to see it in action.

**myapp/urls.py**

Add an ajax-like path to urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('create/', views.Create.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('ajax/load-sample-file/', views.load_sample_file, name='ajax_load_sample_file'),
]
```

**myapp/forms.py**

Modify my original forms.py because I know I'll need to insert a link BETWEEN fields so I'll need complete control over the field locations.
Furthermore, I am anticipating for the future implementation of Bootstrap so I'm adding those form classes.

```
from django import forms
from .models import ModelTwo

class ModelTwoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    model_name = forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    upload_file = forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control-file'})
    class Meta:
        model = ModelTwo
        fields = ['name', 'model_one', 'upload_file']
```

**myapp/templates/myapp/create_form.html**

Instead of using `{{ form.as_p }}` in my template, I will need to write out each field (I'm using Bootstrap 4 classes below). Note: if you use crispyforms, you don't have to do any of this and can easily render a form field with `{{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}` (for example).

Callouts:

1. id of form is named `uploadForm`
2. form has an attribute named `data-sample-file-url` which will point to a URL
3. must include jquery link to CDN or local file
4. I have a custom.js file in myapp's static location (explained below)

```
{% extends 'myapp/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container col-5">
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
              id="uploadForm" data-sample-file-url="{% url 'ajax_load_sample_file' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}">Name:</label>
                {{ form.name }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ form.model_one.id_for_label }}">Model one:</label>
                {{ form.model_one }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="sample-file-placeholder"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ form.upload_file.id_for_label }}">Upload file:</label>
                {{ form.upload_file }}
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block custom_js %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'myapp/custom.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**myapp/static/myapp/custom.js**

This is the javascript and AJAX code that enables showing a link dependent on the dropdown value. The idea is it generates a `GET` request and we capture that request in a function-based view and grab those URL parameters from the URL to return the sample file of the selected dropdown object.

```
$("#id_model_one").change(function () {  // #id_model_one is the ID of the Model one field in the form
    var url = $("#uploadForm").attr("data-sample-file-url");  // get the url of the `load_sample_file` view
    var sampleFileId = $(this).val();  // get the selected model one value (number) from the HTML input
    //alert(sampleFileId)
    //alert(typeof sampleFileId);

    $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
        url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/myapp/ajax/load-sample-file/)
        data: {
            'samplefile': sampleFileId       // add the country id to the GET parameters (= /ajax/load-sample-file/?samplefile=1)
        },
        success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_sample_file` view function, print it out in alert!
            //alert(data);
            //alert(typeof data);
            $("#sample-file-placeholder").html(data);  // replace the empty div placeholder with the data which is html

        }
    });
});
```

**myapp/views.py**

The `load_sample_file` view GETs the `samplefile=#` value and we look that ID up. If it exists, we pass the link and the name of the `sample_input_file` to the render function's context.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .forms import ModelTwoForm
from .models import ModelOne, ModelTwo

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = ModelTwo
    template_name = 'myapp/base.html'

class Create(CreateView):
    form_class = ModelTwoForm
    model = ModelTwo
    template_name = 'myapp/create_form.html'
    success_url = '/'

def load_sample_file(request):
    sample_file_id = request.GET.get('samplefile')
    #print(sample_file_id)
    if not sample_file_id:
        return HttpResponse("")
    instance = ModelOne.objects.get(id=sample_file_id)
    context = {
        'link': instance.sample_input_file.path,
        'name': instance.sample_input_file.name,
    }
    return render(request, 'myapp/sample_file_link.html', context)
```

**myapp/templates/myapp/sample_file_link.html**

This is the HTML we are rendering / filling into the `sample-file-placeholder` div in the form.

```
<label>Sample File:</label>
<a href="{{ link }}">{{ name }}</a>
```